# Spring Security JDBC authentication login user error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, jdbc

I have problem with modifying code. I had Spring project with Columns email,password,active user.
Now i wanted to make same but with out Activitation check. Changed Spring Security to :

```
#SPRING SECURITY
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password from user where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
```

My Security Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcp;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery).dataSource(ds)
                .passwordEncoder(bcp);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSec) throws Exception {
        httpSec.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll().antMatchers("//adduser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin")
                .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/").usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied");
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity webSec) throws Exception {
        webSec.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/statics/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/*", "/incl/**");
    }
}
```

while Sign in i have exception like this :

```
[2020-03-26 12:30:09 ] [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter][ERROR] An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select email, password from user where email=?]; Column Index out of range, 3 > 2. ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2.
```

Please help, what i need to do :( ?

Comment: Select the enable field too, just don't use it to validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your user's query to read like this, making every user active (=1), effectively ignoring the activity check.

```
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, 1 from user where email=?
```